# Middle Mouse Transforms in Blender 3.0

Tags: transforms

I am using Blender 3.0 and when I select an object, press  <kbd>G</kbd> and then the <kbd>Middle Mouse Button</kbd>, the object immediately is constrained to an X, Y, or Z axis.

When I release the middle mouse button, the object bounces back to wherever it is - it does not stay on the selected axis. I have seen tutorials where the user presses  <kbd>G</kbd> (or another transform), then the <kbd>Middle Mouse Button</kbd>, and a white line guides them to the axis they want to use. Once they release the middle mouse button they can move their object along this axis at will. I would like to have this behavior with my setup. It currently is not working, and I don't know what preferences to check or uncheck to make it work.

[image]

The above picture is what I get when I press  <kbd>G</kbd> then middle mouse with any Blender version after 2.9x.

[image]

The above picture is what I get when I press  <kbd>G</kbd> then middle mouse with Blender 2.83. I would like to get this behavior now, but I can't figure out what has changed in the preferences.

Comment: Wow! I just downloaded Blender 2.83, and the middle mouse behavior works like a charm! The little white line appears and I can easily move my object on any axis. I'm sure there's probably a preference option to make the newer Blender versions behave like this - especially since I see Andrew Price describe it in his new Blender 3.0 Donut tutorial!!

Comment: FWIW, in a standard install, it works fine in 3.0.0, so perhaps you've accidentally changed the keymap entry

Comment: What keymap entry should I be looking for to make it work right? I just downloaded 3.0, and haven't changed anything that I am aware of - and it is not working. It does not work for me in any Blender build after 2.9x. However, it works correctly in a 2.83 version that I installed earlier today.

Comment: I have noticed that there is a new Transform Modal Map in my 2.9x versions and up called "Automatic Constraint". This is activated by the middle mouse button. It is not an option in the 2.83 version (which works for me). When "Automatic Constraint" is checked, Blender assigns a constraint. Once I take my finger off the middle mouse button, the object bounces back somewhere. When I uncheck it nothing happens when I press the middle mouse. ALSO, I tried unchecking ALL Middle Mouse assignments in Blender 2.83, and it still worked "correctly". I can't pinpoint what is making it work in 2.83.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure.  Perhaps you could add a blend file to your question that just has a cube in it that you can't manipulate and I can look to see if I can figure out what's going on?  ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: Thank you. I will try that. Here's my latest observations. I downloaded and installed many Blender builds. MMB transforms worked correctly for me until 2.92. They added the "Automatic Constraint" in 2.91, yet it still worked right for me. I deleted my user preferences and opened 2.92 again - but I loaded the 2.91 preferences (since they worked), but it still behaved incorrectly in 2.92. I will save a default cube from my 2.92 file and you can try opening it. I'm thinking that since it works correctly for you, however, that it will still work correctly. . .

Comment: I agree that it will probably work for me as well, but I don't know what else to try and this should be an easy thing to test.

Comment: All my files work correctly in Blender 2.91 and start acting weird in 2.92 (as far as the MMB is concerned). It doesn't matter which file I try, so, I won't upload a file. I have also been warned not to comment too much, so, I will stop commenting, and hope someone can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer, however, it is giving me some functionality.

I assigned the *Automatic Constraint* to a different button on my Logitech mouse, and with that new button, everything works as it should. If I move it back to the default <kbd>Middle Mouse Button</kbd>, the incorrect behavior returns. So, for now, I am sticking with a new assignment.